# How to upload a downloaded glance image?

Tags: openstack, openstack-glance

I have downloaded a glance image from internet and I want to upload it in the set of glance images how do I do that? I am using devstack. My directory is `/home/mona/devstack/`.

Comment: The user guide has an [entire section on managing images](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/common/cli-manage-images.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either the glance client, or better, the openstack client. First, ensure you are authenticated, then issue (assuming last OpenStack version, Mitaka or Newton):

```
openstack image create "Your Image Name" \
--disk-format qcow2 \
--public \
--container-format bare \
--project $keystoneadminuser \
--protected \
--file YourImageFile.YourIMageExtension:
```

Example:

```
openstack image create "Cirros 0.3.4 32 bits" \
--disk-format qcow2 \
--public \
--container-format bare \
--project $keystoneadminuser \
--protected \
--file cirros-0.3.4-i386-disk.img
```

Again. remember to be properlly authenticated (source your admin.rc to your environment).

Comment: Thank You, It helped a lot.